# Non-stop re-rendering while using Next-Auth in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth, next.js13

This is my "/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js"

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

And sessionProvider.js

```
"use client";

import React from "react";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

const Sessionprovider = ({ children }) => {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
};

export default Sessionprovider;
```

I've wrapped the children in Layout.js with this

```
<html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Sessionprovider>{children}</Sessionprovider>
      </body>
    </html>
```

And this is my page.js

```
"use client";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { authOptions } from "./api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";

export default async function Home() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  console.log(session);

  const _signInWithGoogle = async () => {
   await signIn("google");
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center items-center flex-col gap-3 p-5">
      <h1 className="font-semibold text-lg">Home Page</h1>
      {session ? (
        <button
          onClick={() => signOut()}
          className="p-1 bg-blue-400 text-white font-semibold rounded-md hover:bg-blue-500"
        >
          Sign Out
        </button>
      ) : (
        <button
          onClick={_signInWithGoogle}
          className="p-1 bg-blue-400 text-white font-semibold rounded-md hover:bg-blue-500"
        >
          Sign In
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I run the app, It gets re-rendering non-stop. Any help on this would be appreciated. It still stays in the signIn component since the console shows the user object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `async` from your client component.

```js
"use client";

export default function Home() {
}
```

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48822